# upload form (.vbhtml) and VB controller

Tags: vb.net, razor

I am new to vb programming and have been trying to implement an upload form to upload files to my webserver.  I am using .vbhtml and VB .  I've created the form but when I click on the submit button "Button1_Click" , nothing happens.  here's my code

---- Index.vbhtml code -----

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Home Page"
 End Code  


    <form id="form1" runat="server" action="">
        <div>
            <input type="file" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
            <br />
            <input type="button" ID="submit_button" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
             value="Upload File" />&nbsp;<br />
            <br />
             <span id="Span1" runat="Server" />
             </div>
      </form>
```

-------- code used in the HomeController.vb -------------------

```
Public Class HomeController

Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller


Dim Span1 As Object
Dim FileUpload1 As Object




'Upload file

Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Try
            FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Uploads\" & _
               FileUpload1.FileName)
            Span1.Text = "You have specified a file."
            Span1.Text = "File name: " & _
              FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
               "File Size: " & _
              FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb<br>" & _
               "Content type: " & _
               FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
        Catch ex As Exception
            Span1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
    Else
        Span1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

---

Please let me know if I am missing something .

Comment: You're mixing MVC and WebForms...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it ..
:Controller

'file upload

_
Public Function Index(file As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult

```
If file.ContentLength > 0 Then
    Dim fileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
    Dim path__1 = IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), fileName)
    file.SaveAs(path__1)
End If
Debug.WriteLine("File uploaded")
Return RedirectToAction("Index")
```

End Function

:index.vbhtml

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```